# jQuery replace url to video

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I have a little script i'm using a YoutubeAPI, now i can't get it work whenever i send the `id` trought the `replace` function. I get the video-ID correct to my video function but somehow it doesnt work for me. And i just want to replace the URL with video i want to keep 'Hello this is a post'.

i have the script on http://jsfiddle.net/pb6e7ynh/

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<span id=msg>
    Hello this is a post
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLaNBbKJPfw
</span>

jQuery(function($){
    $('#msg').html(function(i, html) {
        function video(id){
            var player;
            console.log(id);
            player = new YT.Player('msg', {
                height: '174',
                width: '309',
                videoId: id, // videoId: 'eLaNBbKJPfw'
                playerVars: {
                    enablejsapi: 1,
                    //controls: 0,
                    disablekb: 1,
                    fs: 0,
                    iv_load_policy: 3,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    rel: 0,
                    showinfo: 0
                }
            });         
        }
         test = html.replace(/(?:http|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '$1');
        video(test); 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another element to create the youtube player (see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6e7ynh/4/)), because the API will replace it with the `iframe`

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<span id="msg">
    Hello this is a post
</span>
<br>
<span id="youtube">
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLaNBbKJPfw
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function video(id){
    var player;
    console.log(id);
    player = new YT.Player('youtube', {
        height: '174',
        width: '309',
        videoId: id, // videoId: 'eLaNBbKJPfw'
        playerVars: {
            enablejsapi: 1,
            //controls: 0,
            disablekb: 1,
            fs: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            modestbranding: 1,
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        }
    });         
}

$(function(){
    var html, youtubeID;
    html = $("#youtube").html();
    youtubeID = html.split("=")[1];
    video(youtubeID);
});
```

**A bit more advanced :** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6e7ynh/12/)

Comment: I checked your code, but the URL and messages are going in the same place like on Facebook. And it doenst send the `youtubeID` right to the API so it doesnt play it can you check that why the `youtubeID` doenst send right '

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pb6e7ynh/11/ : weirdly as soon as I put the youtube element in the post element it does not work and I don't know why for now ...

Comment: OK here's a working one : http://jsfiddle.net/pb6e7ynh/12/ /!\ for some weird reason, if you indent the HTML code it does not work anymore, I may have missed something obvious OR it's a bug on jsfiddle - and couldn't make the YT API work on codepen, so I can't do more here :)